# How to identify the 3 thermals sensor connectors from the mac mini motherboard?

Tags: power, temperature, mac-mini

I opened my mac mini to switch the DVD with another hard drive and I forgot to take a picture with the ways the 3 thermal sensors are connected.

THeir codes on the mainboard look like:

- J5550 - left one, when you look from the front of the mini (dvd opening towards you)
- J5520 - middle one
- J5560 - right one - the closest to the two sata connectors
- One of them is for the DVD
- One of them is for primary HDD near the connect
- One of them for the primary HDD on the other side (glued)

How do I pair them? It's important as I do not want to mess the logic of power management.

Comment: I have a Mac Mini Server Macmini4,1 (A1347) mid 2010 model. Obviously, this computer has two hard drives. There is no DVD. I have a similar question to the correct thermal sensors connectors. My fan is running high. I am thinking that I have the wrong thermal sensors connected to the logic board. If I am looking down at the logic board, the RAM is on my left, J5550 (DVD) is on the left, J6500 (fan), J5520 is the TOP drive? J5560 is the BOTTOM drive? Do I have to reverse it? Maybe it doesn't matter. I am trying to figure out why the fan is running high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have found the answer via other means, but I'll answer it for the next person that finds their way here.

I was looking for a way to repair the connector on the motherboard when I found this question unanswered.  I'll continue my search after answering.

So, after much double checking:

- One of them is for the DVD.

  - This is connector **J5550**. From your perspective, the left one.
- One of them is for primary HDD near the connect.

  - This is connector **J5560**. From your perspective, the right one.
- One of them for the primary HDD on the side (glued).

  - This is connector **J5520**. From your perspective, middle one

PS: I would recommend including your Mini model in the future.